# Performing calculations on specific rows in dataframe and using the results to perform additonal calculations

Tags: python, pandas

Provided an example table below (In reality, this table would have many more experiments for a given subject, many more samples, and variable numbers of replicates):

```
SujectID    Experiment    Sample    Results
A               1          neg         1
A               1          neg         2
A               1          test-a      123
A               1          test-a      144
A               1          test-b      43
A               1          test-b      54
B               1          neg         42
B               1          neg         45
B               1          test-a      45
B               1          test-a      54
```

I need to calculate the mean of the negatives for a given experiment for a given subject. Then I have to subtract this from the means for each test with that experiment for that subject. I'd like to make that a new column in the dataframe where each replicate gets the result of the calculations with the means.

Now the the first six rows of the table would look like this:

```
SujectID    Experiment    Sample    Results    Adjusted
A               1          neg         1          0
A               1          neg         2          0
A               1          test-a      123        132
A               1          test-a      144        132
A               1          test-b      43         47
A               1          test-b      54         47
```

I can do some of this using 'groupby' and 'mean', but then I'm unsure how to unpack those values back into this table.

```
dataframe.groupby(['SubjectId', 'Experiment', 'Sample']).mean()
```

I can also do this using a python dictionary, but it seems like this is suited for pandas since I have a giant table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach - filter your dataframe to just the negative samples before you do the groupby, then combine back with your larger frame using `merge`

```
neg_sample = df['Sample'] == 'neg'
neg_means = df[neg_sample].groupby(['SujectID', 'Experiment']).mean()
neg_means.columns = ['Adj']

df = df.merge(neg_means, how='left', left_on=['SujectID','Experiment'], right_index=True)
df['Adjusted'] = df['Results'] - df['Adj']
```